# Getting error while running the application in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My App.js file code is like this

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import IndexScreen from "./src/screen/IndexScreen";
const navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: IndexScreen
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

And my index.js file is like

```
import { React } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
const IndexScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>IndexScreeen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default IndexScreen;
```

But after running the application I am getting this error.
[image]

What is my mistake

Comment: Have you tried to create `IndexScreen` as a class that extends `React.Component` and have a function `render()` inside? Also, your file is named `index.js` and you are trying to import file `IndexScreen` ?

Answer (score 3):

You are importing `import IndexScreen from "./src/screen/IndexScreen";` and you said your file is named as `index.js`, is that right?

By the way, I get an error when I try `import { React } from "react";`. However if I try `import React from "react";` it works.

Comment: no I have made a mistake in the question actually file name is IndexScreen.js and I have used your suggestion of importing React insted of {React} but still face the same issue.

Comment: @Utpal if you made mistake on the question, then edit it and fix, to avoid people answering you with wrong solutions caused by your mistaken code...

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. You are importing IndexScreen, instead of index.js
2. It's not `import { React } from "react";`. It's `import React from "react";`
3. You are using const to Export from the file. The Export to use it as a react component you should probably do :

```js
    class IndexScreen extends React.Component {
        render() {return (
            <View>
                <Text>IndexScreeen</Text>
            </View>
          );
        }
    }
```

Comment: no I have made a mistake in the question actually file name is IndexScreen.js and I have used your suggestion of importing React insted of {React} but still face the same issue.

Comment: have you tried removing node_modules files and installing it again? Maybe it will help you know.

Comment: Ahh, I think I found the issue. You are not using react Component to output. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Finally solve it , actually I made a mistake to define a function component just after the import without adding a line break or blank line.